# DayClick function in FullCalendar AngularJs works only for first time

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I am opening a modal window with dayclick function in `fullcalendarjs` by setting a flag to `true` when it opens a modal window and making it false when it closes the window. It works perfect for the first time when I click but doesn't work again. What am I doing wrong ?

HERE IS MY CONTROLLER SNIPPET

```
$scope.closeAgenda = function () {
    $scope.isModalAgendaActive = false;
};

$scope.openAgenda = function (event) {
    $scope.isModalAgendaActive = true;
}


    $scope.uiConfig = {
              calendar:{
                height: 450,
                editable: true,
                header:{
                  left: 'prev,next',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'month agendaWeek agendaDay'
                },
                //dayClick: $scope.openAgenda,
                dayClick: function() {
                  $scope.$apply(function (){
                      $scope.openAgenda()    
                  });
                },
                //$scope.alertEventOnClick,
                eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
                eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize,
                viewRender: $scope.renderView
              }
            };
```

here is the html for modal window

```
<div id="modal-Agenda-background" class="modal-background" ng- show="isModalAgendaActive"></div>
<div id="modal-agenda-content"  class="agenda-modal-content" ng-show="isModalAgendaActive" >
   <img id="modal-agenda-close" class ="modal-close" ng-click="closeAgenda()" height="30px" width="30px" ng-src="{{modalCloseImage}}">
   <div id="agenda-container" style="width:100%;height:100%;margin-top: -50px;" ng-  include="Url"></div>
```

Comment: Can you make a full functional example please ? You can do it on jsFiddle or plunker.

Comment: Please provide a demo

Comment: Have you look at this directive for AngularJS ?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar It works with fullcalendarjs